# Google Realtime API - Using Collaborative Models with Files

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

Trying to understand [this help doc](https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/models-files).  It says:

> The Realtime API provides a persistent document for the data that
>   users are collaborating on.

What is this "persistent document"? Is this a file in Google Drive? I'm not planning to store data in Google Drive and most likely will be using [shortcut files](https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/application#shortcut_files). So how does that relate to my situation?

> Applications that provide collaborative
>   editing features, but need to work with files in various formats, must
>   adopt one or more strategies for converting data between the Realtime
>   API document and other file formats.

I'm storing my data as XML in database. Does this qualify for "files in various formats"? How does that effect my situation?

Answer (score 0):

Each file on Drive has content as itself and a permanent storage for Realtime API. In your case, your shortcut files will have Realtime structures even though your files wont have any content all.

Comment: Can you clarify, where this shortcut file points to? Somewhere on client's machine where Realtime structure is stored in memory? Apologies for bombarding with so many questions.

Comment: No realtime components are synced to client at any time and they are only accessible with Realtime API. Imagine you have another service for each file you have on Drive.